# Open a Word 2013 legacy Open dialog in a specific folder

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a simple Word macro that shows the legacy Open dialog.

```
Sub LegacyOpen()
DoEvents
Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen).Show
End Sub
```

I’m now trying to get it to open in a specific folder.
"C:\Users\Paul Schroeter\Documents\Microsoft Word Documents".
After about an hour I have not found an macro argument or example of how to get it to do what I want it to do.

If you wonder why I need to do this, it’s because every time I use “Search documents” in the legacy Open dialog, it resets the Open dialog path to "C:\Users\Paul Schroeter\Documents", which is driving me insane, because I then have to change it back to the folder where I actually keep my Word documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of the built-in Word dialog boxes have "dialog box arguments" corresponding to *some* of the controls/settings in the dialog box. A list can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/built-in-dialog-box-argument-lists-word). These are not part of the Intellisense and are late-bound into the object model. The developer needs to know they exist and how to look them up and use them.

One of these built-in arguments is to set/read the file full name from the File/Open dialog box. In VBA the arguments are usually used in a `With` block. Putting the argument before the `Show` or `Display` method executes the setting before the dialog box is shown to the user. If it's placed after the method, then it's used to read the user's choice.

```
Sub WordFileOpen()
    Dim dlg As Word.Dialog
    Dim sPath As String

    Set dlg = Application.Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
    sPath = "C:\Users\Paul Schroeter\Documents\Microsoft Word Documents"
    With dlg
        .Name = sPath
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works and fixes something that has been aggravating me for six years since I switched to Word 2013. I’m now slightly tormented by the thought of why I couldn’t have thought of this relatively simple fix years ago. I guess I was too fixated on the   “Set default file save location:” Word setting not working like I expected. 
I really, really miss Word not having a built in File Search utility and hate, hate, hate, using Advanced Query Syntax for document searches.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider something different than `Dialogs` collection you could use `FileDialogs` property. Here is working example:

```
Sub OtherWindowType()
    Dim FD As FileDialog
    Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With FD
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "c:\" '...your path here
        .Show
    End With

    'if you want to open the file...
    If FD.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Documents.Open FD.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This does what I asked, but unfortunately it disables the Microsoft Word previewer. When I click a document to see it's content it causes:

"This file cant' be previewed because of an error in the Microsoft Word previewer."

I think it has something to do with the way the dialog opens with the name of the last folder (destination) from the InitialFileName path in the "File name:" text box.  

VBA macros always seem to be full of gotchas.